# Несколько столбцов combobox c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, combobox

На форме есть combobox который заполняется из бд access.
В него загружается несколько столбцов таким образом

```
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            comboMesto.Items.Add(reader["№"].ToString()+ "|" +reader["ФИО"].ToString()+ "|" +reader["Дата"].ToString());


        }
        reader.Close();
```

В combobox отображается все нормально, но мне надо чтоб в таблицу заносилось только первое значение(№).Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Это WinForms? Добавьте метку.

Comment: Под словом "таблица" что подразумевается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108261/222542

Comment: Таблица - datagridview